# Filter array with another array with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to filter an array 'arrSOPrecods' with key values from 'outputdata' another array. the first array 'arrSOPrecods' contains records for users to be trained for a specific SOP the second array 'outputdata' contains records for users already trained for specific SOP I will need to filter out the records that exist in outputdata from arrSOprecords.  I have tried many different methods such as jQuery filter, JavaScript for loop as well as its own .filter function with little progress but nothing useful. here is example of the data and what the final output should be.

```
var arrSOPrecords = [
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" },
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" },
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" },
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 2" },
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" },
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 2" }
];

var outputdata = [
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" }, 
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" }, 
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" }, 
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" }
];
```

the final output array .

```
var filtered = [
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 2" },
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 2" }
];
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a hash table for the items, you want to exclude and filter then the records.

```js
var arrSOPrecords = [{ User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" }, { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 2" }, { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 2" }],
    outputdata = [{ User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" }, { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" }],
    filtered,
    hash = Object.create(null);

outputdata.forEach(function (a) {
    hash[a.User + '|' + a.SOP] = true;
});
filtered = arrSOPrecords.filter(function (a) {
    return !hash[a.User + '|' + a.SOP];
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `map()` on both arrays and return string of `User + SOP` and then use `indexOf()` to filter

```js
var arrSOPrecords=[{User:"Cesar", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Cesar", SOP:"training 2"},{User:"Jon", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Jon", SOP:"training 2"},{User:"Ana", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Ana", SOP:"training 2"}]; 
var outputdata= [{User:"Cesar", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Cesar", SOP:"training 2"},{User:"Ana", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Jon", SOP:"training 1"}]

var a = arrSOPrecords.map(e => e.User+e.SOP);
var b = outputdata.map(e => e.User+e.SOP);

var result = arrSOPrecords.filter(function(e, i) {
  return b.indexOf(a[i]) == -1;
});

console.log(result)
```

**Update**: You can actually just use `map` on second array and then use filter like this

```js
var arrSOPrecords = [{ User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" }, { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 2" }, { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 2" }];
var outputdata = [{ User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" }, { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" }, { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" }];

var a = outputdata.map(e => e.User+e.SOP);
var result = arrSOPrecords.filter(function(el) {
  return a.indexOf(el.User+el.SOP) == -1;
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I tried a couple of suggestions and this one seemed to the trick, thanks to every one for all their suggestions, you are all awesome i greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) + [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
var arrSOPrecords = [
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" },
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" },
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" },
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 2" },
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" },
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 2" }
];

var outputdata = [
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" }, 
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" }, 
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" }, 
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" }
];

var filtered = arrSOPrecords.filter(function(r) {
    return !outputdata.some(function(t) {
        return r.User === t.User && r.SOP === t.SOP;
    });
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try filtering the first array with array.some method:

```js
var arrSOPrecords=[{User:"Cesar", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Cesar", SOP:"training 2"},{User:"Jon", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Jon", SOP:"training 2"},{User:"Ana", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Ana", SOP:"training 2"}];
var outputdata= [{User:"Cesar", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Cesar", SOP:"training 2"},{User:"Ana", SOP:"training 1"},{User:"Jon", SOP:"training 1"}]


var r = arrSOPrecords.filter(x => !outputdata.some(y => _.isEqual(y,x)))

console.log(r)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.13.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

to compare the objects inside `some` method I'm using lodash `isEqual` but you could use something else to test objects.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution using `Array.filter` and `Array.indexOf` functions:

```
var filtered = [], trained = {};

outputdata.forEach(function(o) {
    trained[o.User] = trained[o.User] || [];
    trained[o.User].push(o.SOP);
});
filtered = arrSOPrecords.filter(function(o) {
    return !trained[o.User] || trained[o.User].indexOf(o.SOP) === -1;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered, 0 , 4));
```

The output:

```
[
    {
        "User": "Jon",
        "SOP": "training 2"
    },
    {
        "User": "Ana",
        "SOP": "training 2"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to present generic, reusable solutions for these problems. The following code will list the objects those are present in array that's called upon which are missing in the array that is provided as an argument. We are utilizing two generic methods; `Object.prototype.compare()` and `Array.prototype.diference()`.

```js
Object.prototype.compare = function(o){
  var ok = Object.keys(this);
  return typeof o === "object" && ok.length === Object.keys(o).length ? ok.every(k => this[k] === o[k]) : false;
};
Array.prototype.difference = function(a) {
  return this.filter(e => !a.some(f => f.compare(e)));
};
var arrSOP = [
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" },
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" },
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" },
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 2" },
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" },
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 2" }
],
   outData = [
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 1" }, 
    { User: "Cesar", SOP: "training 2" }, 
    { User: "Ana", SOP: "training 1" }, 
    { User: "Jon", SOP: "training 1" }
],
  filtered = arrSOP.difference(outData);
console.log(JSON.stringify(filtered));
```